# DirectX11 / OpenGL only renders half of the texture

Tags: opengl, textures, directx-11, directx-10

[image]

This is how it should look like. It uses the same vertices/uv coordinates which are used for DX11 and OpenGL. This scene was rendered in DirectX10.

[image]

This is how it looks like in DirectX11 and OpenGL.

I don't know how this can happen. I am using for both DX10 and DX11 the same code on top and also they both handle things really similiar. Do you have an Idea what the problem may be and how to fix it?
I can send code if needed.

[image]
also using another texture.

[image]
changed the transparent part of the texture to red.

Fragment Shader GLSL

```
    #version 330 core

in vec2 UV;
in vec3 Color;
uniform sampler2D Diffuse;


void main()
{

    //color = texture2D( Diffuse, UV ).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( Diffuse, UV );
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(Color,1);
}
```

Vertex Shader GLSL

```
    #version 330 core

 layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
 layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
 layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexColor;
 layout(location = 3) in vec3 vertexNormal;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 World;

out vec2 UV;
out vec3 Color;

void main()
{

    mat4 MVP = Projection * View * World;
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition,1);

    UV = vertexUV;

    Color = vertexColor;

}
```

Comment: For future reference, when writing a GLSL 3.30 core shader, do not use `gl_FragColor` or `texture2D (...)`; those are deprecated. A lot of GLSL compilers will let you continue to use them, but they're not required to. You should use a user-defined fragment output (e.g. `out vec4 frag_color`) and `texture (...)` (this is an overloaded function that takes all sampler types beginning in GLSL 1.30).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

The reason is that I forgot to set the Texture SamplerState to Wrap/Repeat.
It was set to clamp so the uv coordinates were maxed to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly said, it looks like you are using back face culling (which is good), and the other side of your model is wrongly winded. You can ensure that this is the problem by turning back face culling off (OpenGL: glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE​)).

The real correction is (if this was the problem) to have correct winding of faces, usually it is counter-clockwise. This depends where you get this model. If you generate it on your own, correct winding in your model generation routine. Usually, model files created by 3D modeling software have correct face winding.

Comment: hm no turning back face culling off or changing the winding order doesnt change anything. gl_cull_face is disabled (just tested it by turning it on and it results in some similiar but different looking result)

Comment: That was my guess, too, but if it were a back face culling issue, you'd see the other half of the bird as it rotated around. This looks like only half the bird is getting drawn, but drawn correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but are you telling the system the correct number of polygons to draw? Calls like `glBufferData()` take the size in bytes of the data, not the number of vertices or polygons. (Maybe they should have named the parameter `numBytes` instead of `size`?) Also, the size has to contain the size of all the data. If you have color, normals, texture coordinates and vertices all interleaved, it needs to include the size of all of that.

This is made more confusing by the fact that `glDrawElements()` and other stuff takes the number of vertices as their size argument. The argument is named `count`, but it's not obvious that it's vertex count, not polygon count.

Comment: well they are rendered. I added another picture using another texture. That black side is the one that is not properly rendered. I also changed the transparent part of the texture to red , you can see the result above.

Answer (score -1):

A few things that you could try :

1. **Is depth test enabled** ? It seems that your inner faces of the polygons from the 'other' side are being rendered over the polygons that are closer to the view point. This could happen if depth test is disabled. Enable it just in case.
2. Is **lighting enabled** ? If so turn it off. Some flashes of white seem to be coming in the rotating image. Could be because of **incorrect normals** ...

HTH

Comment: depth test is enabled and lighting is not. Those flashes of white are not within the scene, its because of the gif.

Comment: ok. it looks (from the newer images you posted) that the normals are off. Would you mind pasting some code ?

Comment: I do have normals but I am not using them anywhere yet because I am not at the point of using lightning.